# Javascript multiple media queries possible?

Tags: javascript, jquery, media-queries

I'm looking into a way for JavaScript to understand more than one media queries. At this point I've the following code to check the width of the browser, but I want to create more queries. Google (and Stack) only showed me the code I've already written. The only way what I see is to use enquire.js, but I want to know if there isn't another way.

```
$(function() {
// Screen width check 
if (matchMedia) {
    var mq = window.matchMedia("(min-width: 992px)");
    mq.addListener(WidthChange);
    WidthChange(mq);
}

// Run function mq (check screen width)
function WidthChange(mq) {
    // Screen size +992px
    if (mq.matches) {
        .....
    }
    // Screen size -992px
    else {
        .....           
    }
// End widthChange(mq) function
}
// End Function script
});
```

So this code will only check for min-width: 992px, but now I want atleast 3 more.

Comment: Just to be clear, is your goal to find out the screen width of the user's browser?

Comment: @EthanFischer No, I want css media queries like media screen (min-width 999px) { } etc in Javascript/Jquery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can match multiple things by either having two (or more) query's or making a joint one.

**Multiple query's**

```
function screenIsWide() {
  var mq = window.matchMedia("(min-width: 992px)");
  return mq.matches;
}

function screenIsToWide() {
  var mq = window.matchMedia("(max-width: 9001px)");
  return mq.matches;
}

function isPrint() {
   var mq = window.matchMedia("print");
   return mq.matches;
}

console.log(screenIsWide() + " " + isPrint() + " " + screenIsToWide());

if(screenIsWide() && isPrint() && screenIsToWide()) {
   // do stuff
}
```

**Joint**

You can make this really easy just as in normal CSS
Read more here [w3schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_mediaqueries.asp)

```
function isScreenAndIsWide() {
  var mq = window.matchMedia("screen and (min-width: 992px)");
  return mq.matches;
}

console.log(isScreenAndIsWide());
```